# Spring 4 @RequestMapping -- consumes vs headers?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm learning how to build RESTful web services using Spring 4, and one thing I'm not clear on is in @RequestMapping.  I've seen examples where one uses `headers = "Accept=application/xml"` and other examples using consumes (or produces) `= "application/xml"`.

For instance, in my own @RestController class, I have this function...

```
// POST
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/xml")
public User create(@RequestBody User user) {
    LOG.info("User = " + user.toString());
return userService.create(user);
}
```

What is the difference between using `headers = "Accept=application/xml"` vs. using consumes `= "application/xml"?`  Or even using `headers = "content-type=application/xml"`?

Could someone explain the differences between headers and consumes/produces, and when each is used?

Answer (score 40):

**SHORT ANSWER**
In the example you have above, using `headers = "Accept=application/xml"` or `produces = "application/xml"` will both respond to the client the same way i.e. send a response to the client with XML representation.

**LONGER ANSWER**
***i. Headers***
For RESTful web services, the client (e.g. your browser) sends a request (e.g. GET, POST, etc.) to a server, and the server will send a response back. This is an HTTP Transaction. Both the request and response have HTTP header fields ("headers"), which define the operating parameters of an HTTP transaction (I will refer to the headers for client request as "request headers", and these differ from headers from server response "response headers").

As part of the request your browser sends to server, there are different request headers and some examples include `Accept`, `Connection`, `Content-Length` etc. and each of these headers have their own function (see a full list of headers here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

Using your code example, if a client does a POST request, Spring will check the request header(s) and if it finds a header `Accept` with a value of `application/xml`, it will map the request to the `create` method you have above (and in your case the server will return an XML response representation to the client).

Let me modify the `headers` element in the code you provided:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Connection=keep-alive")
public User create(@RequestBody User user) {
 ...
}
```

Notice the `headers` element now has a value of `Connection=keep-alive`. If a client does a POST request, Spring will check the request header(s) and if it finds a header `Connection` with a value of `keep-alive`, it will map that client request to the `create` method above.

***ii. Produces and Consumes***
If you used `produces="application/xml"` for the `create` method, this means a client request is only mapped to the `create` method if the client's `Accept` header matches `application/xml`. This essentially is the client saying, "Hey server, I prefer to accept your response in XML representation, so send your response to me in XML". Effectively, the `produces="application/xml"` is also the server saying, "Hey client, I can only produce responses for you in XML representation, so I will send you that format". 
[Link to Spring documentation reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces).

If you used `consumes="application/xml"` for the `create` method, this means a client request is only mapped to the `create` method if the client's `Content-Type` header matches `application/xml` (the `Content-Type` request header describes the representation the client request is coming in). This essentially is the server saying, "Hey client, I can only consume requests in XML representation, so send that format to me".

**SUMMARY**
The `headers` element within the `@RequestMapping` annotation can take different request headers (`Accept`, `Connection`, `Cache-Control` etc.), but the `produces` element is only concerned with the `Accept` request header and the `consumes` element is only concerned with the `Content-Type` request header.

Comment: This answer should be mark as an accept answer. by the way thank you Alex for the detailed and informative answer.

Comment: Any idea why [this is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044639/file-upload-wont-work)?

Answer (score 3):

As the javadoc of [`HeadersRequestCondition`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/HeadersRequestCondition.html) (which handles the value provided in the `headers` attribute of a `@RequestMapping` annotation) states

> Expressions passed to the constructor with header names 'Accept' or
>   'Content-Type' are ignored. See [`ConsumesRequestCondition`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ConsumesRequestCondition.html) and
>   [`ProducesRequestCondition`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition.html) for those.

So don't use those headers in `headers`. Use the `produces` and `consumes` attributes for `Accept` and `Content-Type`.

As to how to use them, the documentation gives examples: [for `consumes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-consumes) and [for `produces`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-produces).

Comment: I don't think it's ignored, there is nothing about it in official documentation. Moreover it does work. Anyway, using produces and consumes is preferable.

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk They are ignored in `HeadersRequestCondition`. See the source code, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/HeadersRequestCondition.java#L65). However, those same values are also passed to the `ProducesRequestCondition` and `ConsumesRequestCondition` when building a `RequestMappingInfo` for the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34138501/java-illegalstateexception-on-http-response#34138501).

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk Also, the quote in the answer is from the javadoc.

Comment: There is a little misunderstanding between us. I totally agree with you that HeaderRequestCondition ignores Accept and Content-type headers and we do see in the source code. But the initial question was about placing the header in "headers" parameter and it perfectly works, just because as you said "hearers" also passed to [ProducesRequestCondition](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition.java#L105) Sorry for confusion :)