# File upload won't work with angular-file-upload and Spring

Tags: angularjs, spring, http, angular-file-upload

I am trying to make a simple file upload possible but Spring does not want to play with me.

This is the endpoint for file uploads - currently not doing a lot:

```
@PostMapping(WordEmbeddingApiPaths.UPLOAD_MODEL)
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
public ResponseEntity<WordVectorListDto> uploadModel(
        @ModelAttribute("file") MultipartFile file,
        // @RequestBody Object obj,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    LOGGER.debug("POST uploadModel");

    return new ResponseEntity<WordVectorListDto>((WordVectorListDto)null, HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

I've tried several things but it all ends up in different errors. I've just tried to use `@RequestBody` because I thought maybe that's the trick but then I get an exception saying:

```
Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarycV8dFSvDV6U9OwJq' not supported
```

or

```
Content type 'multipart/form-data' not supported
```

depending on what I just tried.

If I go with `@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file` I see

```
Required request part 'file' is not present
```

which is similar for `@RequestParam("file")`.

I have no idea what's so hard on this but I hope somebody can tell me how I can get that file from the client.

Below you can see the request I've sent to the endpoint:

Is this request okay?

[image]

---

Web Client:

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/rest-api/dl4j/we/uploadModel'
});

uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function($modelFile) {

    console.info('onAfterAddingFile', $modelFile);

    var fd = new FormData();        
    fd.append('file', $modelFile.file);

    $http.post($modelFile.url, fd, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        },
        transformRequest: angular.identity          
    })
    .then(
        function (data) {
            alert("upload success");
        }, 
        function (data, status) {
            alert("upload error");
        }
     );
};
```

index.html

```
<label class="btn btn-default btn-file" style="float:right;">
    Upload 
    <input 
        type="file" 
        style="display: none;"
        name="file"     
        multiple    
        nv-file-select                  
        uploader="uploader">
</label>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File upload won't work with angular-file-upload and Spring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42044639/file-upload-wont-work-with-angular-file-upload-and-spring).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i didi it:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/uploadFile", method=RequestMethod.POST)
            public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(
                    @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
                String name = "test11";
                if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                        BufferedOutputStream stream =
                                new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name + "-uploaded")));
                        stream.write(bytes);
                        stream.close();
                        return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name + "-uploaded !";
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
                    }
                } else {
                    return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
                }
            }
```

**and dont forget to register the multipart resolver:**

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10000000);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

**here is the html code ... take a look at the name/id of the input fields ..**
    
    
        File1 to upload:

```
    Name1: <input type="text" name="name">


    File2 to upload: <input type="file" name="file">

    Name2: <input type="text" name="name">


    <input type="submit" value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
</form>
```

Comment: `@RequestParam("file")` does not work because Spring keeps telling me the parameter was missing.

Comment: I ve updated my anwser ... take a look at the html code ...... name of input type file is ... file

Comment: Well, I have it similar and from the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjVfJ.png) I think the parameter has been set correctly.

Comment: Ok, not sure but in the screenshot you have @RequestHeaders Contentype:multipart/form-data;  boundary=-----WebKitFormBoundary
I Think the boundary=-----WebKitBoundary does not belong there.... do you have an ideqa where it comes from?

Comment: I am not sure, I am not sure where this comes from but it might come from angular's file upload. However, I've added the JavaScript and HTML parts from the client to my question.

Comment: i can only guess ...  headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined
        }

Comment: No, that can't be the issue. The header is getting set as can be seen from the actual request that is being sent - one has to set it to undefined - I know that looks strange but yeah ..

Comment: Remove consumes = {"multipart/form-data"} in handler and try. input content type doesnt match with the content  type defined in consumes field